# Crashlytics and obfuscated Flutter stack traces

Tags: flutter, dart, crashlytics

Is there a way to send symbols from `flutter build appbundle --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=...` to Crashlytics for automatic deobfuscation?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Mapping files to deobfuscate Android stacktraces on Crashlytics can be uploaded automatically by configuring `firebaseCrashlytics.mappingFileUploadEnabled` to **true** in your app/build.gradle as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android#keep-obfuscated-build-variants).

However, if you're referring to [Android NDK crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports), here's the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports#add-extension) that you can follow to automatically upload symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Omatt, but the symbols I'm trying to upload are an output of the Flutter build... I don't think they're either Android SDK or NDK artifacts.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried adding the config and see if there's a mapping file uploaded for your Android build? The config should automatically upload the mapping file for your Android build. 

If they're not Android artifacts, it'll be helpful if you could share a screenshot of the obfuscated stack trace that you're getting.

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question.  I can take the stacktrace from the 'TXT' tab and manually deobfuscate it using `flutter symbolize` but it really feels like Crashlytics should be doing that for me.

Comment: I see. I've checked similar issue tickets and it looks like the deobfuscation process might be needed to be done manually for release builds as mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7199#issuecomment-947570964), and has been treated as working as intended.

Comment: I filed a feature request with the Firebase team to add this option to Crashlytics.  It passed triage.  Hopefully it will be implemented soon.

Comment: @Sundog Could you give me the link to the feature request? Thanks.